# Identify the start of token in boost tokenizer

Tags: tokenize

`std::string s = "this string will be modified"; boost::tokenizer<> tok(s); for (auto it = tok.begin(), it_end = tok.end(); it != it_end; ++it) { std::string::difference_type const offset = it.base() - s.begin()- it->size(); //do some operations on string s }`

I need to find the start of each token and then suppose delete 3 characters from this token. This process will be repeated for the whole string. The offset calculated in this way is not correct if string is modified. Any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::tokenizer<> tok_t;

    std::string s = "this string will be modified"; 
    tok_t const tok(s);
    for (tok_t::const_iterator it = tok.begin(), it_end = tok.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        std::string::difference_type const offset = it.base() - s.begin() - it->size();
        std::cout << offset << "\t::\t" << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

See [this C++ demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G8OxEwMIwFcHtxdC). Output:

```
0   ::  this
5   ::  string
12  ::  will
17  ::  be
20  ::  modified
```

Comment: I have to modify the string within while loop.(suppose delete one character from first token in s). In that case, will this offset be correct for the next token ?